# Tensorflow data set encoding issue for labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to find code in text documents. I got a data frame with code and text.
My input for the model is text+mixed code, and the output is just the code inside the text so I could clean that later.

I assume that I have quite a few issues here. My obvious one is that I don't encode the labels part of my data set.

My current error is:

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
```

This happens when I run `model.fit()`.

```
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  df_tmp = dataframe.copy()
  labels = df_tmp.pop("labels")

  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df_tmp), labels)).batch(batch_size).shuffle(batch_size)

  return ds


def encode_string_feature(feature, name, dataset):
  feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])
  feature_ds = feature_ds.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))

  encode_string_feature.vectorize_layer.adapt(feature_ds)

  encoded_feature = encode_string_feature.vectorize_layer(feature)
  return encoded_feature

encode_string_feature.vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
      standardize = 'lower_and_strip_punctuation',
      max_tokens=max_features,
      output_mode="int",
      output_sequence_length=sequence_length,
)


train_ds = df_to_dataset(df_train, batch_size=batch_size)
input_text = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='text', dtype="string")
all_inputs = [ input_text ]
encoded_text = encode_string_feature(input_text, "text", train_ds)

#  Model Creation:
text_features = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_features, embedding_dim, input_length=sequence_length)(encoded_text)

text_features = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embedding_dim, input_shape=(None, sequence_length), return_sequences=True))(text_features)
text_features = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embedding_dim, input_shape=(None, sequence_length))(text_features)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(text_features)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=all_inputs,
    outputs=output_layer,
)

model.summary()

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(train_ds,
                    validation_data=val_ds,
                    epochs=epochs)
```

Comment: There's no `model.fit()` in your code...

Comment: Added, it's just one line at the end of the code.. figured it was alright to omit.